# Why does GitHub say, "Repository not found" when I have just cloned it?

Tags: git, github

Trying to make a simple change to a Git repository, privately hosted
with GitHub. I cloned the repository, made the change and went to push it up for
review. The `git push` didn't succeed and I thought maybe I had fat fingered the
remote URL when I cloned the repository (but that *couldn't* be right because
I'd *successfully* cloned the repository, right?). I tried removing and
re-adding the remote but pushing still fails:

To illustrate the problem:

```
% git remote -v               
origin    https://github.com/our-organisation/some-repository.git (fetch)
origin    https://github.com/our-organisation/some-repository.git (push)

% git fetch -v origin
From https://github.com/our-organisation/some-repository
= [up to date]        MO_Adding_ECS_configs             -> origin/MO_Adding_ECS_configs
= [up to date]        update_gems                       -> origin/update_gems

% git push -v origin
Pushing to https://github.com/our-organisation/some-repository.git
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/our-organisation/some-repository.git/' not found
```

[Some names may have been changed.]

Why does GitHub say, "Repository not found" when the remote URL is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Check your write permissions on the repository!

Some of my colleagues helpfully suggested I try an SSH remote. So I
do this...

```
% git remote add ssh git@github.com:our-organisation/some-repository.git

% git fetch ssh
From github.com:our-organisation/some-repository
* [new branch]        MO_Adding_ECS_configs             -> ssh/MO_Adding_ECS_configs
* [new branch]        update_gems                       -> ssh/update_gems

% git push ssh     
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

"The correct access rights?"

Well *why didn't you say so?*

It's worth noting at this point that while the SSH failure mode in this scenario
is *slightly* better, I use HTTPS remotes over SSH because
[GitHub *recommend* HTTPS over SSH](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/#cloning-with-https-urls-recommended).

I understand that GitHub uses "Not Found" where it means "Forbidden" in some
circumstances to prevent inadvertently reveling the existence of a private
repository. This is a fairly common practice around the web.

> Requests that require authentication will return `404 Not Found`, instead of
>   `403 Forbidden`, in some places. This is to prevent the accidental leakage of
>   private repositories to unauthorized users.

--[GitHub](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication)

What makes no sense to me is when I am authenticated with GitHub using a
[credential helper](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/)
*and* I have access to that repository (having successfully cloned and fetched
it) that GitHub would *choose* to hide its existence from me because of missing
write permissions.

Checking https://github.com/our-organisation/some-repository/ using a web
browser confirmed that **I didn't have write permissions to the repository**. Our
team's GitHub administrators were able to grant my team write access in a short
time and I was able to push the branch up.

Hopefully this Q & A will help folks in the future.